# what does '-O' option do in 'curl' command of git bash?

Tags: curl, git-bash

What will happen if I use a normal word instead of a url with '-O' in 'curl' command?
e.g. What will happen if I type following command? :

curl -O https://openhatch.org/missions/diffpatch/diffsingle/nutty-pancake.txt -O original

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Save the URL as a different file name?

Answer (score 6):

That wouldn't work: the [man page for curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) do mention:

```
-O, --remote-name
```

> Write output to a local file named like the remote file we get. (Only the file part of the remote file is used, the path is cut off.)
>
> The remote file name to use for saving is extracted from the given URL, nothing else.
>
> Consequentially, the file will be saved in the current working directory. If you want the file saved in a different directory, make sure you change current working directory before you invoke `curl` with the `-O`, `--remote-name` flag!
>
> There is no URL decoding done on the file name. If it has `%20` or other URL encoded parts of the name, they will end up as-is as file name.
>
> You may use this option as many times as the number of URLs you have.

It means that option doesn't take parameter, but instructs curl to use the remote url(s) as a template for the local filename.
Using it more than once doesn't make sense.